# UILocal notification without prompting the user?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I've seen some answers about this but couldn't understand -

Can I show local notification to the user without PROMPTING him to register for remote notification, without asking him for any permission for that matter?

Comment: YES, you don't need to register for Remote Notification to get a Local Notification, however whatever you implement, whether it is Local or, Remote iOS will ask for confirmation from the user whether they want the app to send Notifications, it can be Local also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before ios8, registering for local notifications in the code wasn't necessary but with ios8 apple added `registerForUserNotifications` which you must call for both / either remote or local notifications

so no, you cannot avoid prompting the user

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm hearing from you,it might actually be the case of a special notification[like a custom notification]

This is just the way I see it,so I would recommend using `cocoa pods`,for example a notification I used about a year ago in `Swift` was this one:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/ALAlertBanner

[edit]: some local notifications: https://cocoapods.org/?q=local%20notification

Comment: I'm trying to use something that can be called when the app is in the background or even terminated. still relevant?

Comment: as a matter of fact it is....I think you can find a custom notification in the cocoa pods